# Express Postgres Sessions not working correctly

Tags: postgresql, express, express-session

I'm using `express-session` and trying to use Postgres as my session store:

```
app.use(session({
    store: new (require('connect-pg-simple')(session))(),
    secret: 'mysessionsecret',
    resave: false,
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
    }
  }));
```

But when I run my server, I get

```
2016-05-07T14:19:05.571491+00:00 app[web.1]: error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "my.ip.address", user "myuser", database "databasename", SSL off
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var pgSession = require('connect-pg-simple')(session);
app.use(session({
    store: new pgSession({
        conString : process.env.DATABASE_URL
     }),
     secret: 'mysessionsecret',
     resave: false,
     cookie: {
         maxAge: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
     },
     secure : true
 }));
```

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a `secure` option

Answer (score 1):

There is no entry in PostgreSQL's host-based authentication file `pg_hba.conf` for host "my.ip.address", user "myuser", database "databasename", with SSL off.

You probably have PostgreSQL configured to only accept connections from the loopback address `127.0.0.1`.

See [the manual for `pg_hba.conf`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) and more generally [the client authentication chapter](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/client-authentication.html).

---

OK, so [`connect-pg-simple` gets its connection info from the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable by default](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-pg-simple). From the comments you're trying to connect to a Herkoku PostgreSQL instance, presumably from outside Heroku where `DATABASE_URL` isn't set. So you should set the `DATABASE_URL` env var to an appropriate value, making sure `sslmode=require` is included (see the Heroku documentation) or pass the URL as the `connString` parameter to `connect-pg-simple`.

Comment: Well, that would've been a useful detail to include at the start. For Heroku your problem is that *Heroku requires SSL connections* and *you are not attempting to connect with SSL*. You seem to be using some kind of wrapper called `connect-pg-simple`; [the manual for it](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-pg-simple) suggests that it reads the connection string from `DATABASE_URL` in the environment if running on Heroku etc. If not available, you should specify a connection string. I don't know Node.js, but I suggest passing the parameter `connString` as your Heroku `DATABASE_URL`.

Comment: Right - but I'm not specifying the DB connection anywhere, so I'm not sure where to specify the connection for the session

Comment: @Shamoon See the manual for `connect-pg-simple` linked above; set `DATABASE_URL` in the environment or pass the `connString` parameter.